# Where can I find the executed query of cognos 11.1 report?

Tags: oracle, report, cognos-11

I have a report on **Cognos Analytics 11.1**, with prompt pages. When I run the report

> I want to see/find the query which is executed on oracle DB

with the prompt values that I am passing through.

Do you know If there is a log file , which keeps this info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe use the property Generated SQL to view the query

For Cognos 11

- From query explorer.  Select the query and change the property Use SQL Parameters to Literal
- Next, Ctrl + Alt + M will reveal the menu options at the top for -- File, Edit, View

Select Tools

Then choose Show generated SQL/MDX

Comment: Through this option I can see the query  which is going to be executed at the db, before the substitution of the Parameters. From over there I see in my query  this expression :  **AND  a.open_date between to_date(#prompt('Parameter1','varchar')#,'rrrr-mm-dd')**. I wan to see the query after the substitution of the Parameter1. Do you know where can I find it?

Comment: See updated instructions - select the query and change the property 
**Use SQL Parameters** to Literal

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool called Toad which is a client tool for developing and administering Oracle databases. When I worked with Cognos with Oracle as database, I could check the SQL sent to Oracle by Cognos using a feature in this client called "Session Browser" I think, where (if you have enough permissions) it was possible to view the last SQL queries executed by the users.

I guess there must be some kind of internal Oracle table where this information is stored. But that's something to ask in some Oracle DBA tag.